# npm automatic versioning when committing through PhpStorm

Tags: git, npm, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to push projects to git and would like to automate the project versioning. After some googling around, I found about `npm version` and utilized that.

But now having a bit of a problem. I created a pre-commit script that updates project's version number and if I omit the `--no-git-tag-version`, I get the error `Git working directory not clean.`. If I leave that tag in, the package.json and package-lock.json are being updated with new version, but then those two files are excluded from the commit. To me it looks like PhpStorm creates a list of all files to be committed and since those two .json files are not on the list, they are not being pushed into commit. If I push them with next commit, the entire process repeats (files committed, new version is written and then they are again "new" files with uncommitted changes and it creates an endless loop).

How can I automate the versioning properly by using git and PhpStorm?

I opted for a pre-commit command because if use `prebuild: "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch"` on the pipelines, then the version won't be updated properly since version in my local package.json won't change. I will always deploy same version and then that version will increase by one patch on the server, so it will always be off.

Comment: You deleted your question _"PHP return true for 10% of executions"_ after 2 hours and 8 reactions. You didn't react to any comments. Please be aware that this behavior is detrimental to the functioning of Stack Overflow. This is the reason that the [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) contains a header: _"Respond to feedback after posting"_. I advice you to read it. Regrettably I see this kind of behavior more and more.

Answer (score 0):

If your pre-commit script edits the file, it will stage them, too. So please add .git add command in the script after editing operations are done.